# Is there a way to sign a Firebase custom token using a service account from a different project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I would like to use *signInWithCustomToken* to a secondary project using a token signed by a service account from a primary project.

At the moment I get "Error: The custom token corresponds to a different audience."

I was hoping that adding the signing service account to the secondary project with the Role: Service Account Token Creator would be enough to accept its tokens but it is not.

Is there anything else I can do to get this setup to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is "it is not possible". See statement from a Firebase team member

*"A service account can only sign tokens for one and only one project. Any token signed by service account Foo is only valid within the parent project of Foo."* -- hiranya911

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/634#issuecomment-525953070